# How to use multiple && ORs in a PHP If statement?

Tags: php, html

How I adjust this in order to get the brackets to work?

```
if (mysql_num_rows($printPricealertsdata) < 5 && ($_POST['pricetype'] == "pricebelow" && $_POST['price'] < $marketdata['priceusd']) OR ($_POST['pricetype'] == "priceabove" && $_POST['price'] > $marketdata['priceusd'])) {
   echo "success";
}else{
   echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: Won't help in this case. || binds tighter than OR, but && binds even more tightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you told us what you want, and what you get with your code. But since you make me guess, I think you print "success" sometimes, even when the number of rows is 5 or more; and you don't want that. If that's the problem you need brackets around your OR-clause, because && binds closer. [Check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) for the precedence of different operators.

BTW you can use new lines and indentation to make your code more readable:

```
if ( mysql_num_rows($printPricealertsdata) < 5 
  && (
  ($_POST['pricetype'] == "pricebelow" && $_POST['price'] < $marketdata['priceusd']) 
  OR 
  ($_POST['pricetype'] == "priceabove" && $_POST['price'] > $marketdata['priceusd']) 
  )) {
   echo "success";
 } else {
   echo "fail";
 }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks alot! Thats exactly what i wanted to achieve and its working perfectly! :))

Answer (score 0):

Try this (without placing brackets around each condition):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($printPricealertsdata) < 5 && $_POST['pricetype'] == "pricebelow" && $_POST['price'] < $marketdata['priceusd']) OR $_POST['pricetype'] == "priceabove" && $_POST['price'] > $marketdata['priceusd']) {
   echo "success";
}else{
   echo "fail";
}
```